# How to compute the area on top of this red green line?

Tags: area

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient

I says that if u people own f portion of the wealth, then the gini index is f-u.

They draw some triangle there

[image]

It seems that the area on top of the green line and to the left of the red line is simply .5(f-u)

However, I know no easy way to compute that. Pencil pushing confirm the calculation.

Are there simpler ways?

I  know the formula hold if f is equal to 1. When f is less than 1 the area of the triangle shrink proportionally. Well, not really. So yea I am looking for better derivation here.

Note: f + u is NOT 1

It's u people have f incomes.

Answer (score 1):

The triangle of interest has coordinates $(0,0)$, $(1-u,1-f)$ and $(1,1)$ when visited in counterclockwise order. So compute its area as a determinant using the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula#Proof_for_a_triangle):
$$
\frac12\left|
\begin{matrix}
1&1&1\\
0&1-u&1\\
0&1-f&1\\
\end{matrix}
\right|=\frac12\left((1-u) - (1-f)\right)=\frac12(f-u).
$$
Using the shoelace formula you can prove that a triangle with one vertex at the origin and the others at $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ will have area $\frac12|ad-bc|$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

First of all, note that 
$$
f+u = 1
$$
is assumed.

Now you will notice that the area $A$ can be calculated as $(A+B+C+D) - B - C - D$.

1. $A+B+C+D$

It is nothing but a right triangle with width 1 and height 1.

Therefore,
$$
A+B+C+D = \frac{1}{2}(1 \times 1) = 0.5
$$

2. $B$ and $C$

It is a right triangle with width $u$ and height $f$.

$$
B = C = \frac{1}{2}(f \times u)
$$

3. $D$

It is square, therefore

$$
D = u^2
$$

Now we have

$$
A = \frac{1}{2} - fu - u^2
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2} - u(f + u)
$$
, and 
$$
= \frac{1}{2} - u
$$
because $f+u =1$.

However, from $1=f+u$,
$$
 \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(f+u)
$$
, and we have
However, from $1=f+u$,
$$
 \frac{1}{2} - u = \frac{1}{2}(f-u)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't I notice this.

Take a line from top left of square D to the left hitting the hypotenuse. The length of that line is f-u. Let's called that segment e

[image]

e divides triangle A into 2 regions. e, is a base of those 2 triangles. The sum of their height is 1.

Hence, the area of A is simply .5(f-u)*1 which is what we want.

How do I modify the pictures and write math notation better? What software you use?